# Nativescript Chart zoom is not returning the zoom scale value in the event

Tags: angular, nativescript

Currently using nativescript angular. I'm using the RadCartesianChart in displaying graph data.  Using the DateTimeContinousAxis for the horizontalAxis and the DateTimeContinousAxis has a majorStep property that displays whether it is Year, Month, Week or Day. The RadCartesianChart also has an allowZoom feature that allows in zooming the chart. Now one of the requirement the client wants is it wants to dynamically change the majorStep value everything the user zooms the chart where zooming in will change it to a Day value and zooming out to max will change it to Year value.

The problem here is that the chartZoomed event for the chart is not returning any scale values everytime the chart is zoomed.

I have tried accessing the objects that is being returned in the eventData but no zoom scale value is being returned in there.

And here is my example code.

**chart-sample.component.ts**

```js
export class ChartAxesDateTimeComponent implements OnInit {
    private _dateTimeSource: ObservableArray<Stock>;

    constructor(private _dataService: DataService) { }

    get dateTimeSource(): ObservableArray<Stock> {
        return this._dateTimeSource;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._dateTimeSource = new ObservableArray(this._dataService.getDateTimeSource());
    }
    zoomLevel = 3
    eventFunction(args) {
        console.log(Object.keys(args.object));
        console.log(Object.keys(args));
    }
}
```

**chart-sample.component.html**

```html
<RadCartesianChart tkExampleTitle tkToggleNavButton [horizontalZoom]="zoomLevel" (chartZoomed)="eventFunction($event)">
    <DateTimeContinuousAxis tkCartesianHorizontalAxis allowPan="true" allowZoom="true" minimum="01/02/2015" maximum="01/10/2015" majorStep="Month" dateFormat="MMM-dd"
        labelFitMode="Rotate" labelRotationAngle="1.2"></DateTimeContinuousAxis>
    <LinearAxis tkCartesianVerticalAxis allowPan="true" allowZoom="false"></LinearAxis>

    <AreaSeries tkCartesianSeries [items]="dateTimeSource" categoryProperty="TimeStamp" valueProperty="Amount" chartZoomed="testing($event)"></AreaSeries>
</RadCartesianChart>
```

This is the return of the event data being returned and accessing the properties of those objects shows nothing about the zoom scale which is what I needed to perform the dynamic majorStep value based on the scale of the zoom.

```js
[eventName, object, pointData, pointIndex, series]
```

Any help, suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You mean the event is never fired? `chartZoomed` is missing event binding in your HTML code.

Comment: The event is fired but the data being returned after firing the event shows nothing about scale values...I'm using the latest angular which is version 7 and latest nativescript their event binding is enclosed with parenthesis. Is it possible that maybe the chart is the one missing this feature?